# Spring 4 with thymeleaf Internationalization not identify message from resource properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Working on my webapp with Spring 4 + thymeleaf to support internationalization. I try a lot ways change position files and configurations of basename and still receiving ??label.greeting_**?? on template result. Below are my code

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.categorybags.web.controller", "com.categorybags.persistence.services"})
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/res/**").addResourceLocations("/res/");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");

        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en"));
        return localeResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("WEB-INF/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }
}
```

properties files are under WEB-INF which paths are src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\messages_en.properties and src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\messages_ch.properties

Comment: What's with the displayed label : ??label.greeting_**??, did you put the '**' ? It should be ??label.greeting_en?? or ??label.greeting_ch?? or any locale detected by the LocaleResolver. Also it's probably nothing but try using the Locale.ENGLISH instance when configuring your LocaleResolver, better than creating a new locale instance.

Comment: @m4rtin they are ??label.greeting_en?? and ??label.greeting_ch??, depends on the language detected by LocaleResolver. And switching to Locale.ENGLISH does not make any change on result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I was able to reproduce your problem by only registering the `ViewResolver` to Spring and not the 2 other components that are `SpringTemplateEngine` and `ServletContextTemplateResolver`.

So I think you should try to split your configuration a little to register those 2 other components to the spring container. Here's the code :

```
@Bean
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    viewResolver.setOrder(1);
    return viewResolver;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It solves my problem, is that because missing templateResolver or templateEngine which Spring needs?

Comment: Yes it's not obvious but I think somewhere under the hoods those dependencies are needed by Spring and Thymeleaf to resolve the internationalization messages (among other things).

Comment: Right, all blame their documentation :)