# Spring MVC: message source doesnt seem to point to the properties

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

I have been stuck for several days now on this.

Here is my WebMvcConfig class:

```
package utils;

import Beans.Users;
import com.mycompany.fanalweb.backingbeans.Roles;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Set;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.TemplateResolver;

@ComponentScan({"com.mycompany.fanalweb.controllers", "com.mycompany.fanalweb.backingbeans", "utils", "Utils"})
@ImportResource({"classpath:SpringConfig.xml", "WEB-INF/webflow-config.xml", "WEB-INF/aop-config.xml"})
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".xhtml");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateResolver.setOrder(1);

        ServletContextTemplateResolver flowResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        flowResolver.setCacheable(false);
        flowResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/flows/");
        flowResolver.setSuffix(".xhtml");
        flowResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        flowResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        flowResolver.setOrder(0);

        Set<TemplateResolver> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(flowResolver);
        set.add(templateResolver);

        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolvers(set);

        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        viewResolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);

        return viewResolver;
    }

    //session users and roles
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Users sessionUser() {
        Users u = new Users();
        return u;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Roles sessionRoles() {
        Roles u = new Roles();
        return u;
    }

    //internationalization
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return localeResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("/international/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("language");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

}
```

Here is my WebAppInitializer :

```
package utils;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{
            SecurityConfig.class,
            WebMvcConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}
```

The application is launching well but on my login page, my "international texts" are not translated.
For instance, I have: ??user.mail_en?? , ??user.password_en??

My properties files are located in : src/main/resources/international
They are called: messages.properties and messages_fr.properties

I already tried:

- to put them in WEB-INF but without success.
- to change messageSource.setBasename("/international/messages"); to messageSource.setBasename("international/messages");  => no success

No errors are displayed and the page is rendered correctly ( pictures, CSS,...) except for those "international messages".

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

[Spring 4 with thymeleaf Internationalization not identify message from resource properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159685/spring-4-with-thymeleaf-internationalization-not-identify-message-from-resource)

To make a summary: you need to define 3 distinct beans for viewResolver, templateResolver and templateEngine. You cannot define all in the viewresolver definition.
It seems that Spring demands the 3 distinct beans to work properly

Answer (score 0):

Just guess: From [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html):

> Note that the base names set as "basenames" property are treated in a
>   slightly different fashion than the "basenames" property of
>   ResourceBundleMessageSource. It follows the basic ResourceBundle rule
>   of not specifying file extension or language codes, but can refer to
>   any Spring resource location (instead of being restricted to classpath
>   resources). With a "classpath:" prefix, resources can still be loaded
>   from the classpath, but "cacheSeconds" values other than "-1" (caching
>   forever) will not work in this case.

so maybe just try: `classpath:/international/messages`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` you have to prefix your basename with the `classpath:`. So in your case:

```
classpath:/international/messages
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this but with no success. The issue is elsewhere. Do you have other ideas ? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to rename your messages.properties file to messages_en.properties ? Not sure if that will work, but spring tries to find specific messages file by the given locale beyond the underscore. Of course make sure your locale is en or fr, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I tried it but no success I wonder if the error could come from the fact that I add my WebMvcConfig to my RootConfig and not my ServletConfig